# How to redirect my log output from logcat to the SD-Card on an android device?

Tags: android, logging

I'm trying to redirect the log of my app to the sdcard file. But i failed to do so. I'm trying something like this.

```
String cmd= "logcat -v time   ActivityManager:W  myapp:D  *:* >\""+file.getAbsolutePath()+"\"";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

I tried the -f option also but it is not working either.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

use `logcat -f <filename>` in order to dump it to a file in the filesystem.
Make sure the filename you're using is in the sdcard, i.e. starts with `/sdcard/...`.

Also, in order to pass arguments to the `logcat` program, you should pass the `exec` method an array of strings (and not one string):

```
String[] cmd = new String[] { "logcat", "-f", "/sdcard/myfilename", "-v", "time", "ActivityManager:W", "myapp:D" };
```

Finally, if all else fails, use the full path for logcat: `/system/bin/logcat` instead of just `logcat`.

Comment: thanx for reply..I tried the same but i am getting empty file

Comment: please note that it may take some time for the logfile to show contents, as it might be buffering writes to the file (and writing a few KB at a time)

Comment: And another important thing - make sure your app has the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_LOGS permissions - or it won't allow it to read logs and write them to the sdcard .

Comment: And note that regular SDK apps cannot hold `READ_LOGS` as of Android 4.2 or thereabouts.

Comment: how to filter by package name

Answer (score 26):

This is my worked version:

```
try {
    File filename = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/logfile.log"); 
    filename.createNewFile(); 
    String cmd = "logcat -d -f "+filename.getAbsolutePath();
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

find your logfile /sdcard/logfile.log

Comment: I still get an empty file logFile.log. I already added WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_LOGS permissions

Comment: `-d` leads to only writing the current buffer. Logcat then stops to write any additional data. See bear's answer to get continuous writing.

Answer (score 4):

```
   /**
     * Launches a logcat process.
     * To stop the logcat preserve the use:
     * process.destroy();
     * in the onBackPressed()
     *
     * @param filename destination of logcat output
     * @return Process logcaat is running on
     */

    public Process launchLogcat(String filename) {
        Process process = null;
        String cmd = "logcat -f " + filename + "\n";
        try {
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            process = null;
        }
        return process;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. But where should I put this code? How will I start the process??

Comment: Put the code above in your *main_activity* class. Then create a **private Process process** and in the *onCreate* method pupulate it like this: **process = launchLogcat("sdcard/log.file");** and you are done!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a space after every element in the string. Otherwise, it will consider as a single line command without spaces and do nothing.

Comment: hi,
   I tried,its giving me empty file...This is wat i tried,
File filename = new File("/sdcard/logfile.log");
filename.createNewFile();
String[] cmd = new String[] { "logcat ", "-v ","time ", "ActivityManager:W ", "myApp:D ","*:* " ,"\""+filename.getAbsolutePath()+"\""};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting an empty log file, try change the extension of file from `.log` to `.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void saveLogInSDCard(Context context){
    String filename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "project_app.log";
    String command = "logcat -d *:V";

    try{
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;
        try{
            File file = new File(filename);
            file.createNewFile();
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
            while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
                writer.write(line + "\n");
            }
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```