# Android writing log to the file

Tags: java, android, logging

By default, Log class in android writes logs to console (logcat). Is there any simple way to write logs f.e. in some file?

Comment: if you take a naive approach of just opening a file handle and writing there - you will be writing to the file system on your Android device, while what you need is probably a file system on your dev machine?

Comment: Do you want to export logcat messages to a file or just write log messages in files?

Comment: I want to export logcat messages into file.

Comment: this library might be what you want: http://code.google.com/p/android-log-collector/

Comment: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756296/android-writing-logs-to-text-file

Comment: I can paraphrase my question like "How can I access logcat on android?". I need to do it inside my application to be able to work with this data - f.e., to write it into file. Log-collector library is almost what I need, but not exactly.

Comment: Well, I suppose here is an acceptable solution http://code.google.com/p/microlog4android/

Comment: Refer this [thread][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359692/how-to-redirect-my-log-output-from-logcat-to-the-sd-card-on-an-android-device

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63817908/8168420 try this code for the error log

Answer (score 10):

A simple `Log` class (development/testing purpose only) similar to `android.util.Log`, but logs to sdcard. Only modification to the existing code will be to change the `import android.util.Log` to `import com.example.Log`. Also add permission as 
 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

```
package com.example.logger;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;  

import android.os.Environment;

public class Log {
    private static final String NEW_LINE =  System.getProperty("line.separator") ; 
    public static boolean mLogcatAppender = true;
    final static File mLogFile;

    static {
        mLogFile = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),  "logs.log" ); 
        if ( !mLogFile.exists() ) {
            try {
                mLogFile.createNewFile();
            }
            catch (final IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        logDeviceInfo();
    }

    public static void i( String TAG, String message ){
        appendLog( TAG + " : " + message );
        if ( mLogcatAppender ) {
            android.util.Log.i( TAG, message );
        }
    }

    public static void d( String TAG, String message ){
        appendLog( TAG + " : " + message );
        if ( mLogcatAppender ) {
            android.util.Log.d( TAG, message );
        }
    }

    public static void e( String TAG, String message ){
        appendLog( TAG + " : " + message );
        if ( mLogcatAppender ) {
            android.util.Log.e( TAG, message );
        }
    }

    public static void v(String TAG, String message ){
        appendLog(TAG + " : " + message);
        if ( mLogcatAppender ) {
            android.util.Log.v( TAG, message );
        }
    }

    public static void w( String TAG, String message ) {
        appendLog( TAG + " : " + message );
        if ( mLogcatAppender ) {
            android.util.Log.w( TAG, message ); 
        }
    }

    private static synchronized void appendLog( String text ) {
        final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");

        try {
            final FileWriter fileOut = new FileWriter( mLogFile, true );
            fileOut.append( sdf.format(new Date()) + " : " + text + NEW_LINE ); 
            fileOut.close();
        }
        catch ( final IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void logDeviceInfo() {
        appendLog("Model : " + android.os.Build.MODEL);
        appendLog("Brand : " + android.os.Build.BRAND);
        appendLog("Product : " + android.os.Build.PRODUCT);
        appendLog("Device : " + android.os.Build.DEVICE);
        appendLog("Codename : " + android.os.Build.VERSION.CODENAME);
        appendLog("Release : " + android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is just for dev purposes, you can invoke logcat on the device and redirect its output into a file. For example: `adb shell logcat > log.txt`.

Alternatively, you could try redirecting `stdout` and `stderr` to a file, iirc this will work but I don't have my phone with me to test it.

However, it would be easier to just make your own basic logging class that does the same thing as the built in one but also saves to a file.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse ddms there is a option to save logs into file.

Answer (score -1):

Redirect all error messages to file using FileInputStream

Comment: How would he do this?  Can you provide some links or sample code?