# How to store logcat output with all filters & tags in a file on SdCard?

Tags: android, android-logcat

i am using this code to save logcat output to sdcard :-

```
    public String ReadFromCMD(String[] strCmdArgs)
    {

     ProcessBuilder cmd;
     String result="";
     try
     {
          cmd = new ProcessBuilder(strCmdArgs);
          Process process = cmd.start();
          InputStream in = process.getInputStream();

          BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            int read;
            char[] buffer = new char[4096];
            StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

            process.waitFor();

            while ((read = reader.read(buffer)) > 0) 
            {
                output.append(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            reader.close();
            result = output.toString();
            in.close();

     } catch(Exception ex){ ex.printStackTrace(); }

     return result;
}
```

here i am able to save logs to file.

with this command.

```
String[] args_Logs_Save = "/system/bin/logcat -v time -d -b radio -b events -b main -b system".split(" ");
ReadFromCMD(args_Logs_Save);
```

question here is :- logs save is for only my application package, not complete logcat output with "I/WifiHW, W/ActivityManager, D/hwcomposer, D/wpa_supplicant" etc tags...

when i execute "/system/bin/logcat -v time -d -b radio -b events -b main -b system" manually from adb shell, it will execute successfully and give me all output

but when i execute from above my code, it will only give output for my package only.

so now what to do for getting all logcat from my above code ?

Note:

i am using Android 4.1 & 4.2

reference links : [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982263/how-to-write-entire-logcat-in-to-sdcard), [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686314/logcat-output-on-sdcard), [Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686314/logcat-output-on-sdcard), [Link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970169/stream-android-logcat-output-to-an-sd-card/9039352#9039352)

if you know then please help, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Before Android 4.1 all apps with the `READ_LOG_PERMISSION` could access logging from other programs, but this was changed in Android Jelly Bean. For security reasons Android 4.1 and later only allow you to read logging from your own program. Unfortunately, this change has not been documented by Google (see also [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/6U4A5irWang))

AFAIK the only workaround is to root your device and then either run your program as root or run this command `chmod 04755 /system/bin/logcat` (see also [this post](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/28864/7574))

Comment: Thanks for your help, i will check your links and try with my code. then accept your answer.