# logCat in separate process creates right number of logs but ignores file size

Tags: java, android, logcat

In our Android App we wish to capture Log messages.
We kick off a `Process` which invokes LogCat, asking for rolling logs.

LogCat starts. *We get rolling logs.* We get the right *number* of files. In fact allAll the arguments we specify are honored *except for the individual file size* argument, `-r`.  No matter what argument we specify for -r we get individual 16K files.  We've tried `-r 10000` and `-r 250` and `-r 100` and `-r 64`.  Always 16K files.

**EDIT:** `-r 12` (smaller value) also ignored - get 16K files.

**EDIT:** As of a few months ago, `LogCat` spontaneously started to honor our size argument.  *It must have been a bug that they fixed.*  Thanks all.

---

**What are we doing wrong?**

Here's the call we make:

```
logcat -f /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.my.app/files/MyAppLogs.txt -v time -n 20 -r 64 CookActivity:D CookingService:D destroy:W distcooked:D finishedSpeaking:D freeMealReceived:D gotFocus:D keptMenu:D settingNextWakeAlarm:D settingReTryAlarm:D speakBroadcast:D speakerDestroyed:D stopped:D timeupdate:D dalvikvm:W dalvikvm-heap:W MyImageCache:D LogCatManager:D MainActivity:I MainActivity:D *:W *:E
```

If you're curious:

1. We take the code structure and file system checks from this and other StackOverflow pages:
   [Android unable to run logcat from application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219345/android-unable-to-run-logcat-from-application?rq=1)
2. We take the call to exec() from this page and others:
   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[])
3. From other places we learned that we have to request the app permissions for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_LOGS

**EDIT:**  The class we use to manage logCat:

> package com.example.my.app.main;
>
> import java.io.BufferedReader;
>      import java.io.File;
>      import java.io.IOException;
>      import java.io.InputStreamReader;
>
> import android.app.Activity;
>      import android.os.Environment;
>      import android.os.SystemClock;
>      import android.util.Log;
>
> /**
>       * Manages starting the external logCat process and shutting it down.
>       *
>       * When this is asked to start an instance of logCat for this application and one is already running,
>       * a second one is not started.
>       *
>       * When this application is shut down gracefully, it tries to shut down its instance of logCat.
>       *
>       */
>      public class LogCatManager {
>         private static final String TAG = "LogCatManager";
>
> ```
>    //The process for logCat - set up initially, tear down when we're done.
>    Process logSaveProcess = null;
>
>   // logcat -f /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.my.app/files/MyAppLogs.txt -v time -n 20 -r 64 CookActivity:D CookingService:D destroy:W distcooked:D finishedSpeaking:D freeMealReceived:D gotFocus:D keptMenu:D settingNextWakeAlarm:D settingReTryAlarm:D speakBroadcast:D speakerDestroyed:D stopped:D timeupdate:D dalvikvm:W dalvikvm-heap:W MyImageCache:D LogCatManager:D MainActivity:I MainActivity:D *:W *:E  
>
>    //The index to which the output file name string should be assigned.
>    static final int logCatOutputFileIndex = 2 ;
>    //The index to which the number-of-Kbytes-in-each-logfile threshhold should be assigned.
>    static final int logCatLogKSizeIndex = 8;
>    //The index to which the number-of-logfiles should be assigned
>    static final int logCatLogNLogsIndex = 6;
>    String logCatTokenArray[] =  { 
>           "logcat"
>           ,"-f"
>           ,"--THE_OUTPUT_FILE_NAME_GOES_HERE--"
>           ,"-v"
>           ,"time"
>           ,"-n"
>           ,"--THE_NUMBER_OF_LOGFILES_GOES_HERE--"
>           ,"-r"
>           ,"--THE_MAX_LOGFILE_SIZE_GOES_HERE--"
>           /*\
>            *  entries after this are search criteria - logCat entries matching these are included in the saved file 
>           \*/
>           ,"CookActivity:D"
>           ,"CookingService:D"
>           ,"destroy:W"
>           ,"distcooked:D"
>           ,"finishedSpeaking:D"
>           ,"freeMealReceived:D"
>           ,"gotFocus:D"
>           ,"keptMenu:D"
>           ,"settingNextWakeAlarm:D"
>           ,"settingReTryAlarm:D"
>           ,"speakBroadcast:D"
>           ,"speakerDestroyed:D"
>           ,"stopped:D"
>           ,"timeupdate:D"
>           ,"dalvikvm:W"
>           ,"dalvikvm-heap:W"
>           ,"MyImageCache:D"
>           ,"LogCatManager:D"
>           ,"MainActivity:I"
>           ,"MainActivity:D"
>           /*\
>            * these mean 'anything with W or E, include'.
>           \*/
>           ,"*:W"
>           ,"*:E"
>    };
>
>
>    /** Turns on and off saving logCat data to a file. **/
>    public void setLogSaving(Activity act, boolean shouldStart)
>    {
>       try 
>       {
>           if (shouldStart)
>           {
>               if (logSaveProcess == null)
>               {
>                   Log.i(TAG, "logCat starting LogSaving");
>                   startLogSaving(act);    
>               } else {
>                   Log.e(TAG,"logCat asked to start LogSaving - but saving already happening (process reference not null)! request ignored");
>               }
>
>           }
>           else
>           {
>               if (logSaveProcess == null)
>               {
>                   Log.e(TAG,"could not simply destroy logCat process - have no reference");
>               }
>               else
>               {
>                   Log.i(TAG,"have reference to logCat process object - stopping LogSaving");
>                   logSaveProcess.destroy();
>                   logSaveProcess = null;
>               }
>           }           
>       }
>       catch(Exception e)
>       {
>           Log.e(TAG,"exception in setLogSaving("+ shouldStart + ") - " + e.toString());
>       }
>
>    }
>
>    //10-18-2014 current experience with current software and logCat arguments
>    //  has RM being able to record about 140 minutes of log data in a megabyte.
>    //The settings below attempt to give us more than 10 hours on average before rollover.
>    public final static String SAVINGLOGFILENAME = "MyAppLogs.txt" ; 
>    public final static String SAVINGLOGMAXSIZE = "12" ; //... "64", "100", "250", "10000" (10Meg) too big.
>    public final static String SAVINGLOGMAXNLOGS = "20" ; //10 has also been honored...
>
>    // Took structure and file system checks from this and other StackOverflow pages:
>    //   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219345/android-unable-to-run-logcat-from-application?rq=1
>    //
>    // Took call to exec() from this and others:
>    //   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[]) 
>    //
>    //       ** make sure your app has the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_LOGS permissions **
>    //
>    private void startLogSaving(Activity act) {
>       String filename = null;
>       String directory = null;
>       String fullPath = null;
>       String externalStorageState = null;
>
>       // The directory will depend on if we have external storage available to us or not
>       try {
>           filename = SAVINGLOGFILENAME ;
>           externalStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
>
>           if (externalStorageState.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
>               if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 7) {
>                   directory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
>               } else {
>                   directory = act.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath();
>               }
>           } else {
>               directory = act.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
>           }
>
>           fullPath = directory + File.separator + filename;
>
>           //   Finish token array by contributing the output file name.
>           logCatTokenArray[ logCatOutputFileIndex ] = fullPath ;
>           //  ...and the max size.
>           logCatTokenArray[ logCatLogKSizeIndex ] = SAVINGLOGMAXSIZE ;
>           //  ...and the max number of log files (rotating).
>           logCatTokenArray[ logCatLogNLogsIndex ] = SAVINGLOGMAXNLOGS ;
>
>           Log.w(TAG, "About to start LogCat - " + strJoin(logCatTokenArray, " ") );
>
>           logSaveProcess =
>                   Runtime.getRuntime().exec( logCatTokenArray );
>
>       } catch (Exception e) {
>           Log.e(TAG, "startLogSaving, exception: " + e.getMessage());
>       }
>    }
>
>    // from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978933/a-quick-and-easy-way-to-join-array-elements-with-a-separator-the-oposite-of-spl
>
>    private static String strJoin(String[] aArr, String sSep) {
>       StringBuilder sbStr = new StringBuilder();
>       for (int i = 0, il = aArr.length; i < il; i++) {
>           if (i > 0)
>               sbStr.append(sSep);
>           sbStr.append(aArr[i]);
>       }
>       return sbStr.toString();
>    }
> ```
>
> }

Comment: If you specify a size less than 16k, is the rest of the file above the size actually useful content? For instance, if you specify a size of 8k, does the resulting file contain 8k of useful data followed by 8k of zeroes, or 16k of useful data?

Comment: Show the actual code which sets the arguments to logcat

Comment: @fge - I just tried `-r 12` and got a 16K file.  Good question. :)

Comment: @ChrisStratton - added the LogCatManager class code.