# infinite while loop using bufferedreader

Tags: java, android

I am having a code to store the log files to a SD card in android. The following is the code.

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat "+ LOG_TAG +":D *:S");
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    //do something over here
}
```

It is running an infinite loop. 
Any help.

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804951/is-it-possible-to-read-from-a-inputstream-with-a-timeout - blocking read will not do, you need either `available()` or a timeout.

Comment: It's not running an infinite loop. The loop exits when the peer disconnects.

Comment: @EJP: Yes, it exits when the device gets disconnected. But what if I want some code to execute after the while loop.

Comment: @Joop Eggen: Thanks.. how can I use `available()` with BufferedReader object.

Comment: @Anshu I have turned it into an answer, beause of the code. available is a bit tricky, but might just do here.

Comment: @Joop So you have to change the while loop not to read until end of stream.

Comment: @EJP no, see answer, wrap the original inputstream in a selfmade one, lying that it is finished with -1 on `available() == 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As logCat never ends, you might try to force an end when `InputStream.available() == 0`.
I did this using wrapping the original InputStream in an ImpatientInputStream.

As at the very first start available might be 0 because of the non-blocking nature, you might add a flag whether something read already.

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(
            new ImpatientInputStream(process.getInputStream())
        ));


public class ImpatientInputStream extends InputStream {

    private final InputStream in;
    private boolean eof;

    public ImpatientInputStream(InputStream in) {
        this.in = in;
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        if (eof) {
            return -1; 
        }
        if (available() == 0) {
            eof = true;
            return -1;
        }
        return in.read();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`logcat` never stops, it waits for the next line to display, so `readLine()` blocks while waiting for the next input from the process.

You can however redirect the output of the command directly with `-f filename` as explained [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359692/how-to-redirect-my-log-output-from-logcat-to-the-sd-card-on-an-android-device) answer has everything you need.

Comment: I referred that already.. Doing so, the file is created but no data comes in the file doing this way..

Answer (score 0):

You can provide timestamp/time period in `while` loop. Below sample will make this more clear

Sample :

```
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end_time) {
        //do your stuffs here

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
       //do something over here
        }
        }
```