# Logs rolling over too quickly

Tags: android, debugging, logging, adb

I need to get a longer log history from my Android app running on the Android mobile device.

Even though my app itself does not create a lot of logs (issued via Log.d, Log.w etc), I find that all the logs roll over - apparently caused by all the logs created by Android itself, plus triggered by other apps. At best I am able to get may be an hour or so worth of logs right now.

I have maximized the log buffer size on the device (16 MB).
I tried to convert all my debug logs to warnings (Log.d to Log.w) (note: this may have helped some).

I am trying to get to a day's or so worth of history - without tethering the device to a computer all the time.

Any ideas?

Comment: Stop logging to Logcat and use some logging solution that logs to files.

Comment: Anything you recommend?
I would be concerned with performance impact of any solution that write to flash.  (I think logCat writes  only to RAM, but I could be mistaken)

Comment: "Anything you recommend?" -- there is [a category of logging-related libraries in the Android Arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/57?sort=created). "I would be concerned with performance impact of any solution that write to flash." -- then log less. Or look for logging libraries with good buffering capability.

Comment: >> there is a category of logging-related libraries in the Android Arsenal. ---- Thanks, will check these out.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by redirecting the logs from my app to a file in flash by spawning logcat from the app (when the app starts). See

[How to redirect my log output from logcat to the SD-Card on an android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359692/how-to-redirect-my-log-output-from-logcat-to-the-sd-card-on-an-android-device)

I used the --pid option to logcat to filter logs issued by my app's own process.

Make sure to get WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission (AndroidManifest.xml as well as runtime).