# Android where is log for file for application on device?

Tags: android, logging

I am running a custom android application.  inside that application I have various Log statements.
`Log.i(TAG, "I am in activityA")` etc.  Which log file and directory location will this log file appear in.  Will it print to the log file on device and if so which one? Thanks  Also where do I set levels which will print?  I assume `Log.d(TAG, "")` will not appear on device logs since it needs to be in debug mode ...  Also where to set log levels for deployed app in `manifest`?

Comment: This link will answer your query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882253/how-do-i-get-the-logfile-from-an-android-device

Answer (score 4):

You can use logcat to view the logs. 
You can run logcat as an adb command : Open a command windw on your PC and type

```
$ adb logcat
```

(OR)

```
$ adb shell
# logcat
```

(OR)

You can execute it directly from the shell prompt of your target device.

Comment: Please read more about adb at http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html. If you don't have adb installed, you can get it from http://mobilecon.info/install-adb-in-windows.html