# Retrieve adb logcat files from a client's device

Tags: android, adb, logcat

I'm making an app for a client, and they are experiencing bugs that no one else can reproduce. They are not close to us, so I can't physically go to them and hook their device up to my laptop.

Is there a way that they can get hold of their logcat files without having to install adb on a machine first, i.e. can they email them straight from their device? I'm not sure how tech-savvy they are, and ideally I don't want to spend too much time telling them how to install adb if I can get the files some other way.

Obviously I'm looking to do it with their permission (and I'm expecting that installing adb is going to be the only way).

Edit: I should add that I'm using Corona SDK, so will not be able to access the logs from directly inside the app. Also, all devices are 4.1+ so the various log collector apps have not worked.

Comment: There are various log-collecting solutions, some of which still work if deployed *within* your app even after the security lockdown which prevents them from collecting logs for *other* apps.  If you can send them a custom version, you could even set it up with a shareduserid so you could have the log collecting running in another app running as the same userid.

Comment: Check Google Play for log collector apps if your client's device is prior to Android 4.1 (since that version, the security lockdown mentioned by Chris means these apps are no longer as effective).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redirect the logcat to a file and send it by email using your app.

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359692/how-to-redirect-my-log-output-from-logcat-to-the-sd-card-on-an-android-device) how to save the logcat into a file.

Comment: Ah ok, I'm using Corona SDK so that won't be an option for me. I was hoping there would be some way to access it through the developer options or something like that.

Comment: Can you root the device?

Comment: I'm not sure the client would be willing to, and as I say I'm not in the same location so I can't do it for them.

Comment: The link was helpful - the accepted answer there did the trick, Thanks.  And here's how to open that log file with Gmail from your app  http://stackoverflow.com/a/22367055/2162226