# Open file with default applications in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am making a file explorer in android. So I want when any file is clicked other than directory I want to get a suggestion of apps which can open it and if no app is there then show a dailog. I tried some solutions but nothing worked, so, for now, I am just showing the file is not a directory in the toast

here is part of the code:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    String filename = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    if (path.endsWith(File.separator)) {
        filename = path + filename;
    } else {
        filename = path + File.separator + filename;
    }
    if (new File(filename).isDirectory()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ListFileActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("path", filename);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, filename + " is not a directory", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: "I tried some solutions but nothing worked" -- how are we supposed to help you with code that you are not showing us?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android has some inbuilt [Intent Action Type](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html) which helps you to Open or View specific files, but for this you need to know which type of file you are going to handle.

Suppose If you have file type which categorized in document type you can use,

`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` with specific `MIME_TYPE` (Android 4.4 or Higher)

or If you going to handle some media file (Audio/Video)

you can use,

```
ACTION_VIEW
```

To identify `MIME_TYPE` of specific file you can use function

`guessContentTypeFromName (String url)`[Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#guessContentTypeFromName(java.lang.String))

Or `getMimeTypeFromExtension(String extension)`[Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/MimeTypeMap.html#getMimeTypeFromExtension(java.lang.String))

Comment: Older post but quick reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265298/action-view-intent-for-a-file-with-unknown-mimetype. I suggest you to go with latest `Intent Action`.