# Firebase download file on listview

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am making an app to list the uploaded files and  then I want to download them with an setOnItemLongClickListener.I get download url and use it to get reference for the download process.When I click on a listview item,it says download is succesful.But I can not see the file on my phone.Actually I have no idea about where it should be.
I saw similar questions but I could not find a solution.I really need help to solve this problem.

Here is my code:

```
 listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,
                                       int index, long arg3) {


            try {
           storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(fileFirebase.get(index).toString());


                StorageReference island=storage;

               final File file = File.createTempFile("images", "jpg");
                island.getFile(file).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Download is succesful!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        //taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred();
                        //taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                    }
                });}
             catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Its probably working. use an intent to programmatically open the file with the correct external application. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265298/action-view-intent-for-a-file-with-unknown-mimetype

Answer (score 1):

`File.createTempFile` stores the file in the internal cache directory of Android.

You should `new File` instead and it will be available within the scope of your application directory.

If you are using rooted device or emulator, you can check `/data/data/<package-name>` to see your downloaded file.

And if not rooted, you can browse through ADB shell to this location. In Android Studio 3 you have a built in File explorer to explore the internal data directory of your App which is `/data/data/<package-name>`.

You may also consider storing the file if in the external storage. For this, you need to declare permission in the Manifest file.

```
/* Checks if external storage is available for read and write */
public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/* Checks if external storage is available to at least read */
public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) ||
        Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Check this link for more information: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html

Answer (score 1):

You can get download directory on the device using Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory, see below ...,

For Firebase cloud storage - file upload, download and delete examples, you can see http://www.zoftino.com/firebase-cloud-storage-upload-download-delete-files-android-example#download-file

```
String DOWNLOAD_DIR = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
            (Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath();


  StorageReference storageRef = firebaseStorage.getReference();
        StorageReference downloadRef = storageRef.child(storageFile);
        File fileNameOnDevice = new File(DOWNLOAD_DIR+"/"+fileName);

        downloadRef.getFile(fileNameOnDevice).addOnSuccessListener(
                new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Log.d("File download", "downloaded the file");

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                Log.e("File download", "Failed to download the file");

            }
        });
```