# Open any file with intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I use below link sample code
[ACTION_VIEW intent for a file with unknown MimeType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265298/action-view-intent-for-a-file-with-unknown-mimetype)

I do not have a problem with my phone, but when some users use it they say that even the text file does not recognize Android.

I installed the pdf viewer on my phone and tried to open the pdf file but unfortunately the program did not recognize it

While in my device when i open text file,android open it with htmlviewer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ACTION\_VIEW intent for a file with unknown MimeType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265298/action-view-intent-for-a-file-with-unknown-mimetype)

Comment: @lenik i use this sample code :| but not detect associate app with my file