# Copying the android output

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-embedded-api

I wish to know one thing regarding android apk file and the output generated. Actually I want to take the output that comes after running an apk file, copy the output into another file and use it for some purpose. Friends tell me Can that be done ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you mean log by output, Follow the below link if you want to save the log in to a different output file.

[How do I get the logfile from an Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882253/how-do-i-get-the-logfile-from-an-android-device)

Comment: Thanks.  Suppose i download an Helloworld.apk i want to take the output that displays on the screen re. Is it possible?

Comment: I download an .apk file from internet  and i want to capture the ouput of it into a file. Is it possible.?

Comment: So the output cant be taken into another file ? Actually if i download any TaskManager.apk file it will display the currently running applications but i want to display them using a program. Is it possible, If so kindly help me.