# How to see catlog while running app on mobile device

Tags: android, android-logcat

I have an app that is best tested on mobile device, but I also like to see the catlog output.  How can I see the catlog while running on mobile device?

Edit:  Sorry I wasn't clear.  You know how when you run app on desktop emulator, the eclipse will output logcat outputs?  But I would like to see outputs to logcat when I run my app on a mobile device so to test it better.

Comment: are you want to see on device itself ..?

Comment: I would like to see it on the desktop eclipse's logcat output.

Answer (score 0):

```
in case if you want to see on eclipse : 

Make the debug mode true in manifest. (before making built)
Attach the device in to cumputer using USB cable .
Install the driver (if needed ) 
see the device in the DDMS device section(if not found then restart adb)
click on the device name in device section
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882253/how-do-i-get-the-logfile-from-an-android-device

Comment: Thank!  But i can't find my device in the device view even after starting the adb.  What can I do?  Where is this driver you mentioned?

Comment: driver depend on your device model.for few devices google sdk provide the driver but not for all as http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html