# Capture All Webservice Calls from Android APP

Tags: android

I have an app, and I would like to know the webservice URL that it calls. Is there anyway to find this out?

Comment: Set it to wifi and capture all outgoing requests at the router.  Should work unless it uses https.

Answer (score 0):

You should [check your android logs first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882253/how-do-i-get-the-logfile-from-an-android-device). If the app exposes no info about requests through this, the next best thing would be to [decompile the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/android-getting-source-code-from-an-apk-file?lq=1). If the URL is static, just looking through the data files will get you the address. If it is dynamic, you can modify the dalvik bytecode to have it log to logcat and recompile the apk. If all else fails, you can use tcpdump. You'll need root, and can [follow this tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/analyzing-android-network-traffic/) to utilize wireshark to visualize it easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using app `tPacketCapture`. It can store network dumps in a format that can be read by `WireShark` or other programs on your pc.

Answer (score 0):

or you could set up a proxy for the phone, using fiddler and a PC, like this:
http://www.cantoni.org/2013/11/06/capture-android-web-traffic-fiddler

you'd get all the API requests quite easily then...