# Unity Android Debug Information

Tags: android, debugging, unity-game-engine

Is there anyway of finding out more information about why my application crashes and doesn't run on my android device when I build & run through Unity?

I have no errors on my console inside Unity and the only message I get is `"Unfortunately, "app  name" has stopped"` and that's it. Nothing that can help pin point a reason as to why it hasn't worked.

Comment: You can always run `adb logcat` from a command shell independent of any other tools.  You may (or may not) also be able to run the ddms gui at the same time (for example, trying to have it open both inside eclipse and on its own is often problematic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get Androids logs pretty easily form the device if you're not using a debugger, see the following question: [How do I get the logfile from an Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882253/how-do-i-get-the-logfile-from-an-android-device)

And logs for Unity3D can be found here:
http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/LogFiles.html

As @Chris Stratton mentioned, adb logcat is another straight forward option if you're comfortable with the command line.