# My app runs sooth on my android 4.2.2 phone, my android 4.2.2 tablet and crashes on Lg g2 (4.4.2)

Tags: android

Any idea why this is hapenning?

I don't have money to afford an 4.4.2 mobile phone and in the emulator it doesn't crash.
I don't have also the lg g2, it is from a friend of mine ( and he lives far away ). The code crashes on generating a listview on postexecute.

I'm completly lost at this one.

Comment: This is off-topic, but [here is some suggestions on how to get the LogCat from a phone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882253/how-do-i-get-the-logfile-from-an-android-device).

Comment: Hi Ken, thanks for the quick reply but I use LogCat all the time, the problem in this case is because I'm using a localhost server and he is like the oposite of a nerd ( doesn't even know how to use excel ) so, I'm a bit stuck at this point. 

I wanted to put my app on the play store but this is getting in my nerves and I want to solve it.

Is there any reason why devices like samsung galaxy and as I'm seeing Lg g2 don't run some codes that other devices run?

Comment: You could try using something like Crashlytics to gather crash reports.

Comment: I think you should try a new question with the code that is crashing. You could also add [code like this](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/reading-logs-programatically) to your own app to display the log on your friend's device..