# ADB logcat fails to clear the main log

Tags: android, adb

When I connect to a device or an emulator using adb, I can clear logcat using `adb logcat -c`. The issue I am facing is that I often get the following message:

```
failed to clear the 'main' log
```

AFAIK, 'main' is a non-rooted buffer which means that I should be able to clear it without root. What can then be the reason for this message?

Answer (score 8):

You might have your Android Studio opened, please close it and run again , it should able to clear the logs.

Comment: I'll try but I don't think that it was open at the time

Comment: Closing IntelliJ IDEA worked for me, I guess it was the Android plugin that was causing this issue probably.

Answer (score 8):

use

```
adb logcat -b all -c
```

it will clear all buffers. sometime **adb logcat -c** will not work because of many process using it like android studio.

Comment: This shows me the same error but with 'events' log: ``logcat: failed to clear the 'events' log.``

Comment: @MarcSances there is possibility that by using -b option also we will not be able to clear logcat . That can be because of some lock condition by some process. may be if you can try multiple time same command. Still if it won't work in that case if it is possible then disconnect adb and connect it again.

Answer (score -1):

Logcat messages are stored in buffer, you can try,

```
adb logcat -c
```

> Clear (flush) the selected buffers and exit. The default buffer set is main, system and crash. To clear all of the buffers, use -b all -c.

source: [logcat doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat)

For more logcat usage, check [How do I get the logfile from an Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882253/how-do-i-get-the-logfile-from-an-android-device)

Comment: he is doing the same thing adb logcat -c and he is getting an error