# Read android device logs from my android application

Tags: android, logging, crash, device, logcat

I want to get logs of the whole device, the way logcat shows the processes running in the device.
I want to capture it from within my android application.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882253/how-do-i-get-the-logfile-from-an-android-device

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read logcat programmatically within application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692103/read-logcat-programmatically-within-application)

Comment: These links only provide logs of my app. I basically want the system logs so that when any other app which is present in my device crashes, then I want to know its cause and app name.

Comment: You can't get those, unless you are either rooted or have your app as a system app. Because the `READ_LOGS` permission is a *system level* permission as described [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your app needs to use the permission **android.permission.READ_LOGS**. (unsure if this works on unrooted device).

and you need to grant the permission to your app in runtime to access this permission with:

`adb shell pm grant <pkg> android.permission.READ_LOGS`

(or) programmatically with:

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pm grant <pkg> android.permission.READ_LOGS");`

Then you will be able to get the system logs using shell commands for logcat.
For example, to get a logcat dump as a txt file in the device:

**`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d -f" + " /sdcard/Logcat_file.txt");`**

will get the logs saved in a txt file in the android device , using which further validation can be done.

Comment: this does not work on the non-rooted devices and only gives logs of the app itself and not of the whole device.