# Android app opening with custom scheme issue

Tags: android, android-intent, android-deep-link

I've a strange issue I've this javascript line

```
window.location.replace('kronos://');
```

If the app is already open, it works like a charm but if not it causes app to crash at launch, I don't know how where to dig with the simulator.

EDIT: On the emulator the app is open but blank after opening on the link and I cannot move the app on the foreground.

Comment: You need to check the crash report in the logcat of your android app. If you do not own the app or have no mobile dev to help you, check this answer to get an idea on how to get the logs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50964874/180538

Comment: Ok thanks, now I see that the app does not crash, indeed on the emulator the app is blank ( 
 https://imgur.com/a/eAEJ4nR ) and if I click on the app I've ` W/AppAuth: No stored state - unable to handle response`  in Logcat